# MikTeX 2.8 Update Error "Windows API error 87"

Tags: errors, miktex, updating

I was happily updating packages when the following error appeared:

```
Error: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.
```

The full update report with this error at the very end is as follows:

```
MiKTeX Update Wizard Report

Version: 2.8.3553
Date: Friday, May 13, 2011
Time: 20:22:14
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb2-2.8.tar.lzma...
538036 bytes, 1199.60 KB/Sec
updating package definition directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tpm\packages")...
installed 602 package definition files
visiting repository http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.8.tar.lzma...
106964 bytes, 392.70 KB/Sec
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8"
package repository: http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: eb1794ec380d1dad82ca309893aaa958
going to download 29222566 bytes
going to install 1046 file(s) (60 package(s))
unregistering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\MiKTeX208-core-PS.dll
unregistering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\MiKTeX208-core.dll
unregistering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\MiKTeX208-packagemanager-PS.dll
unregistering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin\MiKTeX208-packagemanager.dll
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/expl3.tar.lzma...
3702662 bytes, 1322.56 KB/Sec
extracting files from expl3.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/latexmk.tar.lzma...
214019 bytes, 477.18 KB/Sec
extracting files from latexmk.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/mhchem.tar.lzma...
256063 bytes, 841.96 KB/Sec
extracting files from mhchem.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-arctrl-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
15294 bytes, 317.78 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bibtex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
50296 bytes, 314.85 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
42207 bytes, 438.49 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
1421335 bytes, 879.61 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-cjkutils-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
32140 bytes, 154.61 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-config-2.8.tar.lzma...
2807 bytes, 88.43 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-config-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-cweb-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
35078 bytes, 218.19 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-doc-2.8.tar.lzma...
2311080 bytes, 976.17 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-doc-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-dvicopy-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
34386 bytes, 308.07 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
221944 bytes, 462.14 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-dvipng-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
33054 bytes, 187.67 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-dvips-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
77697 bytes, 538.13 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-findtexmf-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
13762 bytes, 213.32 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-fontconfig-base.tar.lzma...
8819 bytes, 110.41 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-base.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-fontconfig-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
92834 bytes, 413.96 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-fonts-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
86402 bytes, 490.56 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-freetype-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
100798 bytes, 572.30 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-freetype-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-freetype2-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
195306 bytes, 642.18 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-ghostscript-base.tar.lzma...
515717 bytes, 920.71 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-base.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-ghostscript-bin.tar.lzma...
1143434 bytes, 1231.13 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-graphics-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
279937 bytes, 876.21 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-graphics-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-gsf2pk-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
18298 bytes, 283.64 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-hunspell-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
67100 bytes, 524.22 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-icu-bin.tar.lzma...
1488401 bytes, 1477.15 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-makeindex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
20121 bytes, 316.93 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-metafont-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
122028 bytes, 692.84 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-metapost-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
175368 bytes, 910.95 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mfware-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
65965 bytes, 515.35 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mkfntmap-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
37433 bytes, 388.89 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mktex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
35387 bytes, 317.04 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mo-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
78178 bytes, 610.77 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mpm-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
53472 bytes, 474.72 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mpm-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mthelp-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
25179 bytes, 264.40 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mtprint-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
17507 bytes, 275.75 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-omega-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
312784 bytes, 1028.46 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-pdftex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
410282 bytes, 1168.12 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-poppler-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
435648 bytes, 973.54 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-ps2pk-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
58451 bytes, 607.25 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-psutils-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
20291 bytes, 319.60 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-qt4-bin.tar.lzma...
3602404 bytes, 1230.49 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-qt4-bin.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-runtime-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
795821 bytes, 1602.41 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-teckit-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
23914 bytes, 248.44 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-tex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
137217 bytes, 1072.01 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-tex4ht-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
55626 bytes, 434.58 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-texify-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
56469 bytes, 501.32 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-texinfo-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
80119 bytes, 717.81 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-texinfo-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-texware-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
65985 bytes, 460.27 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-texworks-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
1206559 bytes, 1603.10 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-texworks-doc.tar.lzma...
1052987 bytes, 1462.74 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-texworks-doc.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-vc90-bin.tar.lzma...
2468035 bytes, 1021.70 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-vc90-bin.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-web-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
52963 bytes, 276.59 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
243744 bytes, 725.71 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-xetex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
428565 bytes, 1162.56 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-yap-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
387449 bytes, 1103.11 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-2.8.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zip-bin.tar.lzma...
137464 bytes, 855.05 KB/Sec
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/siunitx.tar.lzma...
658093 bytes, 1177.05 KB/Sec
extracting files from siunitx.tar.lzma...
downloading http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/xpackages.tar.lzma...
3440188 bytes, 977.18 KB/Sec
extracting files from xpackages.tar.lzma...

Error: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.
```

What happened and how do I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Does MikTeX still work? Did you try to reboot and restart the update?

Comment: It worked fine when I tried to compile a simple chemistry document.  All I know is the update failed at some point during the progress meter while my packages were being updated...

No, I haven't rebooted my computer yet.  Maybe it was the fault of the last package being updated before it errored.

Comment: same here!! very annoying! I was trying to install mathstools.sty.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This issue got once reported to the `miktex-users` mailing-list (Nabble archive: 
http://old.nabble.com/Problem-Updating-%28Windows-API-error-87%29-td24971196.html)

The final solution there was:

> It turns out the problem was, I had an instance of MikTex open which was blocking the files needed for the install. After I closed the MikTex instance the install worked fine.

In general it is a good idea to close all application for updates under Windows. On failure reboot the machine and retry it again.

Comment: I see, thanks for finding that report, Martin.  When I reopened update to try again, there was apparently nothing on the list to update.  I guess when new package updates become available, I will try to run the update again and let you know if I have any problems.

Comment: I am sure that this is a feature of Windows. Somehow.

Comment: I had this problem, a background dialogue had popped up during a document build that I hadn't seen. It was prompting me to install the package for miktex. Running that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem - the sollution above didn't work for me, but what worked can be found at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/69152. The sollution is:

> Problem solved. PDFLatex doesn't die after a problematic run due to an
>   uninstalled package. It was blocking some files which, I guess, needed
>   to be modified by the Package Manager. After killing PDFLatex
>   installation run smoothly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note what is written on the [MiKTeX 2.8 Status Page](http://miktex.org/2.8/status): “This version has reached the ‘end-of-life’ status. It will not be possible to install packages from the remote package repository. The current release is 2.9.”

Comment: I actually had a similar problem just now with 2.9. A hanging luatex process was blocking some files. After I killed it, it worked. Still, a nicer error message would be nice...

Answer (score 4):

I found that, for any "Windows API error 87" in MikTeX, deleting all the files in the following folder works.

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le

C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le
```

Comment: This works. I wonder why is that

Answer (score 1):

I have the same trouble, then I tried to re install MiKTeX. Another problem was that install is not posible for "API error 87" ...

This is because another program is using the file, on my case was adobe cloud creative.

If you close the program wich use this dll, then you can actualize, install or use it ...

Other option is seek the file, if don´t appear at the correct place, use the file of acrobat, is the same.

Paste at the root where MiKTeX is installed, normally: `c:program files/miktex2.9/miktex/bin/x64`

Comment: Another good example of why you should always close all programs before any install or update.  And if there are any problems, then do the install only after a full power-off reboot.  And the only program you start is the install or in the case of MikTeX the update program.

Comment: I had Adobe Acrobat open and closing it solved my problem!