# Install package in MiKTeX

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

I'm trying to install new packages on my MiKTeX session with the following path:
Package Manager(admin) from the menu of my computer --> In the box `Name` I write the name of the package, let say for example `fancyhdr` --> then I click on `+` --> but connect failed in tcp_connect. I always receive `Failed in tcp_connect()`.

Please, could someone help me to solve this problem? I can't download any new package. It becomes impossible for me to write a document article.

Comment: What version is your MiKTeX?

Comment: My MikTeX versior is 2.9 i'm very new on Miktex. i'm very in trouble with this software. Thank

Answer (score 4):

Check if
a) your MPM is allowed to connect to the internet (see your firewall/antivirus settings);

or

b) Are you connecting under a proxy? If so, you must setup the proxy through the menu Repository > Change Package Repository > select "Packages shall be installed from the internet" > Connection settings > (enter your proxy settings in the dialog box)

**EDIT**: the solution found in this question [MikTeX 2.8 Update Error "Windows API error 87"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/miktex-2-8-update-error-windows-api-error-87) solved the problem.

Comment: I have just tried to change settings according to what you notice me but unsuccesfully. This is the message  i have got this: "Windows API error 87: Parametro non corretto".  and this at the bottom:  C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\b1cfc6be702f63eea92ca0fbc9559e5c.fndb   Thanks for your help

Comment: When you setup the settings and press "Next", it shows you the list of possible CTAN repository mirrors?

Comment: Also: see if the solution described here helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/miktex-2-8-update-error-windows-api-error-87

Comment: Yes. It shows me different CTAN repository with different countries. I have choosed Italy then the Miktex shows me a message: "Synchronising a database". That is!

Comment: Now it is downloading MikteX packages. It works!. Thank you  Cedric! your link is helpful.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add the link, so it can be helpful to other users. Glad to help!

Comment: I should say that it is not necessary to keep open the MikteX session while the user is downloading new package. User should switch off all the Miktex session and keep only Miktex Package Manager. Thanks again.