# what does error 87 mean?

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error

I have the following when running my code:

```
Process started

ERROR: Windows API error 87: 

ERROR: Line: 83 Sorry, but bibtex did not succeed. You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Process exited with error(s)
```

This is what I am using. It had work before but now I am having problems...

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath} %uso de equaciones
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx} %para introducir imagenes
\usepackage{enumerate} %para enumerar 
\usepackage{makeidx} %para hacer el index 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{rotating} %para rotar la hoja y tabla 
\usepackage{booktabs} %hacer tablas 
\usepackage{adjustbox} %ajustar tabla a hoja
\usepackage{breqn}  %ajustar ecuacion cuando se sale del margen
\usepackage{slashbox,multirow} %para varios textos en la linea de cabeza de 
las tablas
\usepackage{chngcntr} %para contar pie de pagina seguidas
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%para las paginas fancy
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}%\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\textheight22.5cm \topmargin0cm \textwidth16.5cm
\oddsidemargin0.5cm \evensidemargin-0.5cm%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\; #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\; #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}%

\unitlength1mm %Define la unidad LE para Figuras
\mathindent0cm %Define la distancia de las formulas al texto,  fleqn las 
descentra
\marginparwidth0cm
\parindent0cm %Define la distancia de la primera linea de un parrafo a la 
 margen
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\let\PBS=\PreserveBackslash

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\newcommand{\arr}[1]{\raisebox{1.5ex}[0cm][0cm]{#1}}

\usepackage{Befehle}


\hyphenation {Reaktor-ab-me-ssun-gen Gas-zu-sa-mmen-set-zung
Raum-gesch-win-dig-keit Durch-fluss Stick-stoff-gemisch
Ad-sorp-tions-tem-pe-ra-tur Klein-schmidt
Kohlen-stoff-Mole-kular-siebe Py-rolysat-aus-beu-te
Trans-port-vor-gan-ge}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
 \usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor  = blue, 
  citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}     

 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{HojaTitulo/HojaTitulo}
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage} 
{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}\include{Abstract}
\tableofcontents

\label{listoffigures}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}

\label{listoftables}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\include{TabSimbolos}


\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
 \include{Introduccion}

 \include{Econometric} 
 \include{Copulas}
 \include{graficos}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
 \bibliographystyle{apalike}
 \bibliography{Bibli}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: check this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/miktex-2-8-update-error-windows-api-error-87